# Java: runnable JAR file, could not find main class on different computers

Tags: java, jar

I created a little Swing Application. Now I gave it to a friend to test, on his computer it works. 
When he puts the JAR-file on a USB-stick and tries to run it on a different computer, there is an error with the message "Could not find the main class logic.Start. Program will exit.".

Since he isn't very in to computers to check which version he has, I'm pretty sure that the prolbem is the java version on the other computers? My build path according to eclipse is JavaSE-1.7, but it seems that I can not "adjust" the minimum needed as I can do it in Android for example. Is there a way to do this? That I can make it as a JRE5+ application for example?

**EDIT:**

The manifest.mf file is like this

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: logic.Start
(NEWLINE)
(NEWLINE)
```

I've read that there must be only one (NEWLINE). Further the JAR file contains the folders

```
gui / guiDialogs / guiElements / guiHelp / gx / logic (contains Start.class) / META-INF / sounds
```

and no other external JAR's.

Comment: When creating a new project on Eclipse, you can specify which JRE version to use, under "Use an excecution enviroment JRE:"

Comment: @M.M. is it possible to edit this afterwards?

Comment: Yes, right click on a project open its Properties.  In the pop-up select the Java Compiler tree node.  Here you can edit the java versions per project and it includes a link to edit the settings for the entire Eclipse workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the problem was the JRE version on the different computers. As in eclipse the standard JDK is set to 7, and there seems no possibility to change that in an already created project, I created a new project with lower minimu-JRE-level, copy-pasted the whole code in that project and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

If there was a Java version problem the error message would be different.

Your jar file is incomplete (or depends on additional jars which have not been copied along with your main jar file).  The MANIFEST.MF points to the main class `logic.Start` which is not available in the expected location.

Investigate the Class-Path line of MANIFEST.MF file.  You may happen to refer to absolute path names or something similar.

Comment: it's quite possible that I'm referring to absolute paths. But let me pose a noobish question: how can I read the content of the manifest.mf? (It's a runnable JAR-file created from eclipse Export)

Comment: nevermind i found it, now the content is 
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: logic.Start  what does it means that the Class-Path is only "."?

Comment: That "." _is_ the classpath, meaning all the classes not found in the jar, must be present in the file system next to the jar file.  This is most likely your problem.

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "meaning all the classes not found in the jar, must be present in the file system next to the jar file"? See my edit in the original question, I posted the manifest and the structure inside the JAR file.

Comment: I would suggest you spend some time studying now.  The Java Tutorial is an excellent resource:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the step where you create a new project and copy-paste the code in.  Just right click on the line that says "JRE System Library" next to an icon that resembles a stack of books, and click Properties.  Change the Execution environment to the JRE version of your choice.